# Unit testing with -fno-access-control

Tags: c++, unit-testing, gcc

I have seen many crazy methods to get access to private variables when unit testing.  The most mind-blowing I've seen is `#define private public`.

However, I've never seen anyone suggest turning off private variables at the compiler level.  I had always just assumed that you couldn't.  I've complained to many a developer that unit testing would be a lot easier if you could just tell the compiler to back off for this one file.

Then I stumble across the `-fno-access-control` GCC compiler option.  It's so obviously the perfect way to unit test.  Your original source files are unmodified, no injected friends just for the unit test, no recompiling with bizarre preprocessor magic.  Just flick the 'no access control' switch when compiling your unit tests.

Am I missing something?  Is this the unit testing silver bullet I hope it is?

The only disadvantage I see is the GCC-specific nature of the technique.  However, I assume MSVS has a similar flag.

Comment: Have you tried out this technique? Does it work indeed?

Comment: I compiled a simple test case before posting the question.  It does indeed work.  I haven't tried it with any real life or large project but I assume it scales perfectly.

Comment: `-fno-access-control` does not work with private/protected inheritance. I'm stuck with `#define`s.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would argue that unit tests should not need access to private members.

In general, unit tests are meant to test the *interface* to your classes, not the internal implementation. That way, changes to the internals will only break the tests if the interface has been compromised.

Have a look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342037/testing-classes/342065#342065) to a similar question, and the ensuing discussion. It is a controversial topic, to be sure, but that's my $0.02.

Answer (score 2):

I normally try to use only the public interface of my classes in unit tests.  Test Driven Development/Design helps a lot here as the resulting classes tend to enable this style of unit test.

However sometimes you do need to let a unit test access non public members, eg replace the contents of a Singleton with a Fake instance.  For this I use package protection in Java and friends in C++.

Some people seem to bend over backwards to avoid friends but they should be used when appropriate and their use doesn't compromise the design.  They are also declarative and let other programmers know what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Wow this worked perfectly for me.

I was concerned it wouldn't as my unittests need to access private members of classes built in other dynamic libraries (.so files), but it's just what I need.

I only need to declare the flag on my unit test .so compiles (each test is a .so). Not even on the libraries where the objects being accessed are defined.

I needed it for accessing internal widgets on a form to fill in their values; they're not visible to the rest of the program, but needed if my tests are to represent a user entering input. Just thought I'd share a use-case for those private access naysayers :)

Also for completeness, here's my form class, showing the private name_ field:

```
struct EditProduct : public widgets::BusinessObjForm<model::Product> {
public:
    EditProduct (WContainerWidget *parent=0);
protected:
    void fillObjFields();
private:
    // Consts
    static const double minPrice = 0.0;
    static const double maxPrice = 10000.0;
    // Fields
    WLineEdit* name_;
    WTextEdit* description_;
    WSpinBox* price_;
    WFileUpload* image_;
    // Methods
    bool validate();
    void saveProduct(const WString& message);
};
```

and here's the start of my unit test accessing that widget:

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( form_save_test )
{
    EditProduct form(app.root());
    string txt = "this is a product";
    form.name_->setText(txt);
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(form.name_->text(), txt);
}
```