# #define with space

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to write define with spaces such as:

```
#define replace to replacement here
```

I want to replace "**replace to**" with "**replacement here**".

EDIT:

I want to test private members:

I did write

```
#define private public
```

but it didn't work for private slots in Qt

so my intend was to use something like

```
#define private slots: public slots:
```

anyway I have found another way to test slots and by the way I'm aware of that this is an ugly hack.

Comment: As others have said, this is not possible. Turning the question upside down, what is the *goal*?

Comment: Run your source code through a `sed` script if you want to change it permanently.

Comment: You are not allowed to #define keywords anyway, so there is a double fault here. If it didn't work, could it be that some code (a library?) was already compiled with the proper keyword?

Comment: You can redefine keywords.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

no, you can't

`#define identifier something`

what you define must be an ***identifier***  which cannot contain space. Nor can it contain hyphen, begin with a number, etc. you can define only an identifier

what you wrote will work

`#define replace to replacement here`

but not as you expect. This line defined `replace` to be substituted with `to replacement here`

Answer (score 7):

You could do...

```
#define replace replacement
#define to here
```

Watch out for unintended side effects of the defines. You would probably want to `#undef` them after they've done their job.

Answer (score 3):

If you are doing unit test, you can compile your file with the following flag

```
-Dprivate=public
```

Then in your unit test, you will be able to call every private method of your class.

**EDIT:**

I've recently remarked that using the -fno-access-control flag on gcc compiler allows you to access private method or member. More info on that topic can be found here: [Unit testing with -fno-access-control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860923/unit-testing-with-fno-access-control)

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not possible. Why not just do this instead:

```
#define replace_to replacement here
```

Comment: because "replace to" is not written by me.

Comment: Try whether this works with your compiler: "#define replace\ to replacement here". If not, best you can do is probably have your code preprocessed by sed or something similar prior to compilation.

Answer (score -1):

probably not.
It will understand that the first word after the define is the identifier name and the rest is the "body" of that.